# Ubuntu Anonymous Samba Share Now Not Accessible From OSX Machine

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, samba, file-sharing

I have an OSX machine which has been connected as Guest to a Samba share on my Ubuntu machine. It's no longer connecting. When I click 'Connect to Server...' in Finder, and enter `smb://server/anonymous`, it gives the message:

```
There was a problem connecting to the server “server”.
Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. 
If you continue to have problems, contact your system 
administrator.
```

However, I can connect as a registered user on the Ubuntu box but can't edit the files because they are owned by the `nobody` user.

I haven't altered any settings, just haven't tried to connect in a week or so. Any ideas what might have caused this sudden change?

**Additional Info:**

`smb.conf`:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = server
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
#===== Share Definitions =====
[Anonymous]
path = /mnt/raid1
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

On the Ubuntu box:

```
$ smbclient //server/anonymous -U nobody -N
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.8-Ubuntu]
smb: \>
```

And:

```
$ netstat -atn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

On the Mac:

```
$ mount_smbfs -N //nobody:@server/anonymous /test/
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
```

So it looks like I can connect to the share on the Ubuntu machine but not on the Mac.

I've also tried connecting with another Mac but it's the same outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is a known bug between the Ubuntu smbd version 4.3.8 and Mac OS X version 10.11.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1572301

There's no easy resolution yet but should be fixed in due course.